# Interlocking cuts for a truncated cone

Tags: papercutting

I have a simple lampshade design, on the picture is made out of paper:
[image]
It's a basic truncated cone from a single sheet of paper.

I want to join sides of paper with interlocking cuts, like this:
[image]

[image] [image]

Or like in IQ lamp:
[image: puzzle]

How do I go about designing a cut for this single-curvature shape?

Comment: This new lamp is a completely different design. It's made out of several pieces rather tan a single one. I recommend you ask about it in a different question as the process is likely very different.

Comment: To connect two sides of the sheet I want to use some kind of hook-and-loop. The last lamp is just an example of it

Comment: But the second lamp is just slits cut in both sides and then you alternate which is on top. It's extremely simple. If that's not what you want, please clarify what you're looking for.

Comment: Cuts that are more appropriate: https://www.pinterest.com/pin/779545016721846429/ ; https://www.pinterest.com/pin/446771225520016301/

Comment: Please [edit] so your question just has the ideas that you are most interested in, rather than leaving the more appropriate designs in a comment :)

Comment: looking for clarity here: you want it to be held together with the cuts in the paper and not with an adhesive on the back sides of the tabs like in the first example?

Answer (score 2):

From the image of the white lamp shade i think the tabs are not interlocking, but rather interlaced and glued. 
Proper interlocking would not need gluing .. for instance if the tabs where cut as trapezoids and the two edges joined by a series of folding actions to hook the wider ends into narrower inner edges of each tab.

In the other images i suspect they are also interlaced and glued, but that is not clear to me.